# Issue with the \item command

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I have the following document (which is a resume) :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Special chars
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
    }\vspace{-5pt}
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \text{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Large John Doe} \\
john.doe@gmail.com \\
xx xx xx xx xx \\
Imaginary city COUNTRY \\
N\'{e}e le xx/xx/xxxx & \hfill
\smash{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{profil.png}} \\
\end{tabular*}
\\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Compétences}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}

    \item[] \ressubheading{Langages}{}{Node/Express, Typescript, PHP, SQL, Javascript, Python, HTML5, CSS3}{}
    \vspace{0.1cm}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

In fact, the document have two other `\begin{itemize}` sections, and there is more items in the `itemize` showed here but I don't think that it would be helpfull for the question.

The issue is, for each line starting by `\item[]` like :

```
\item[] \ressubheading{Langages}{}{Node/Express, Typescript, PHP, SQL, Javascript, Python, HTML5, CSS3}{}
    \vspace{0.1cm}
```

I have five times the error :

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
```

I already searched about this error and found a lot of answers but to be honest I am far from being an experienced LaTex user and none of the answers I saw solved my issue.

I use the command `pdflatex doc.tex` to create the pdf. This command generates a lot of errors but by pressing enter for each error, the pdf is finally cleanly created.

However, I would like to not have these errors and also learn a bit more about LaTex...

(I am sorry I did not knew which tags to use for this question so I put `itemize` and `enumitem` but I would gladly change it for something more appropriate if an experienced tells me the tags I should use with this question)

Comment: Your main problem is the use of `\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}` in the column specification. Why do you have that in there?

Comment: Your main problem is the use of `\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}` in the column specification. Why do you have that in there?

Comment: I honestly could not tell you, it's a template I found on internet and made my resume from it, if removinf this part of the code should solve the issue, don't hesitate to post it as an aswer and if it's solve my probleme I'll accept it

Comment: @Werner I tried to remove the `\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}`part but it did not change anything. Though I probably did not do it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template incorrectly tries to insert a dot fill between the two columns of your `\ressubheading`. Since this seems like a template consideration/issue that might not be necessary in your use-case, I've just removed it. Secondly, there's a use of `\text` that requires [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), which wasn't included. Instead, I've replaced that with `\textsl`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
  \begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{ l r }
    \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
    \textsl{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
  \end{tabular*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item
    \ressubheading
      {Languages}
      {}
      {Node/Express, Typescript, PHP, SQL, Javascript, Python, HTML5, CSS3}
      {}

  \item
    \ressubheading
      {Devops \& Bonnes pratiques}
      {}
      {Docker, CI/CD via gitlab, TDD}
      {}

  \item
    \ressubheading
      {Base de données}
      {}
      {MySql, MongoDB}
      {}

  \item
    \ressubheading
      {Outils}
      {}
      {Git, Redmine, Visual Studio Code, SonarQube}
      {}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Above is a watered down version of your code since it is the only content pertaining to the problem. Since you're not using the second and fourth argument in the template there might be other options for the display that you're interested in achieving.

Comment: Perfect, I am still aving a few issues but those are not relevant to the question. Thank you very much, sir !